# Magento 2: What Causes the "Failed to enable crypto" Error?

Tags: magento2, ssl, composer

I'm trying to install Magento 2.1 via the composer meta-package with the following command

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

However, composer fails to update the `packages.json` from `repo.magento.com`, and reports

> The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto

Does anyone know what triggers this "Failed to enable crypto" error is and how someone could fix it?

Comment: while retrieving data repo.magento.com it need authentication you should have auth.json in your root directory that will contain magento repository username and password `{
   "http-basic": {
      "repo.magento.com": {
         "username": "a98186c7f7777dbb05d959bdb91b9729",
         "password": "344ce14c479f1c8eae77edb58b4ec66f"
      }
   }
}`

Comment: @amanAlam Are you sure?  Because I've had an auth.json for a while and its worked fine until today.  Also, the error is referencing a crypto problem, not an authentication problem.  What makes you sure it's an auth error?

Comment: Not very much sure because, previously i have some authentication error while installing and it resolved issue so i thought it may help you.

Comment: Check this link this may help you https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4825

Comment: @AlanStorm in your code example, the `--repository-url` isn't spelled correctly. I couldn't make the edit myself, as SE wants a minimum of 6 characters in an edit, and I didn't want to mess with your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like Magento's severely tightened up [their HTTPS](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5239#issuecomment-228422812) on the `repo.magento.com` server.

These settings are tight enough that applications that support HTTPS but use an older version of OpenSSL may have their connections rejected.

Meaning, if the version of PHP you're using to run `composer.phar` is linked against and older version of PHP, you'll get the *Failed to enable crypto* error.  You can test your version of PHP with the following code snippet.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$context = stream_context_create();
$contents = file_get_contents('https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', false, $context);
```

The reason I got this error was/is [the packaged version of PHP](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) I've been using (depending on how you count) for almost 13 years was linking against an older version of SSL.  The package maintainers have released a new build that seems to address these problems.

If you're using a different packaged version of PHP, you'll need to pressure the package maintainers to release a new build that fixes this, or pressure Magento to do the same.

If you're building a version of PHP yourself (by hand, via `brew`, etc) then make sure you're using as modern a version of OpenSSL with modern TLS support (I may have used those words wrong, not an HTTPS/SSL expert by any stretch)

Answer (score 4):

I resolved by updating the OS X liip package

http://php-osx.liip.ch

you just need to run the one-line command on that page

source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_tls-repo.html

EDIT: After this, check that you're using the updated version with `php -v` and `which php`

Thank you @AlanStorm!

Comment: Updating the OS X liip package worked for me.  Without knowing more, if you're still seeing the crypto error my guess would be you're not executing the latest liip version.

Comment: OMG that was FAST! :D Yep you were right, I wasn't using the latest version. I sat an alias for php5.6 in my bash_profile and it worked! Thank you again Alan!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what would cause that error, other than something possibly related to Composer establishing a secured connection over https? But that's just a guess.

I just ran the command right now and it was successful.

Maybe try it again? My apologies for not providing more insight.