# Magento 2.1 module installation error: Component Dependency Check fails due to SSL/Crypto error

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1, ssl

When trying to install a module via the Component Manager of Magento 2.1, I get the following error during the Readiness Check:

```
Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
<warning>The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed</warning>
<warning>https://repo.magento.com could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date</warning>
<warning>The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed</warning>
<warning>https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date</warning>
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

I followed several explanations and solutions, but none seem to fix this issue. I'm using PHP 7.0.8, the latest version of Composer and the latest build of OpenSSL on my CentOS (7.2.1511) system. Furthermore I tried [this fix for error:14090086](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3346) by loading the latest Mozilla Root Certificate Bundle.

Running "composer diagnose" yields one set of errors:

```
Checking composer.json: FAIL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
The version field is present, it is recommended to leave it out if the package is published on Packagist.                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Defining autoload.psr-0 with an empty namespace prefix is a bad idea for performance                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
require.magento/product-community-edition : exact version constraints (2.1.0) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning                                                                                                                                                                      
require.composer/composer : unbound version constraints (@alpha) should be avoided
```

But this doesn't seem the to explain SSL-errors, right? The [solution of Alan Storm](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122583/magento-2-what-causes-the-failed-to-enable-crypto-error) gives some help, but [according to Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/tech_bull_tls-repo.html) my CentOS version should be fine. The weirdest thing is that I'm able to execute "composer update" just fine through CLI ("php composer.phar update" to be precise, since it's not included in my $PATH). Does anyone have an idea why SSL/Crypto is still failing?

Comment: It's a longshot but check your system date. I had a similar error one time because my clock was way off and the certificate failed. I've passed this along to engineering so hopefully you'll get some more help.

Comment: Hey Steve. Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this. Checked the system date & time via CLI, which seems to be fine. Alan Storm suggested ([link](https://twitter.com/ReadySteadyFlow/status/769161291399303168)) that the CLI and web server might be addressing different PHP versions. But `php -v` and a `phpinfo()` page are both showing the same version.

Comment: Does `php -i` also show the same? You want to look for the path to `php.ini` and if there are two paths, you need to change your PHP settings in both.

Comment: Yes, `php -i` yields the same version of PHP and OpenSSL. There also seems to be only one main .ini file. One additional .ini is parsed from _*/php.conf.d_. But this file only states some to be disabled functions.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Is this still an issue?